# spring-kafka: how to pass a method to another method, which (by design) never returns?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

totally new to java.

writing a spring-kafka app, which has the following Kafka listener method:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "receiver-api",
            topicPartitions =
                    { @TopicPartition(topic = "topic1",
                            partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0")))})
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        try {
            JSONObject incomingJsonObject = new JSONObject(message);

                handleMessage(incomingJsonObject);
            }   

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I've been asked to refactor this part of the app into a separate stand-alone package, so the "receiveMessage" could be called, and a method / function could be passed to it, in place of "handleMessage", to process each incoming message.

This "receiveMessage" method never returns, as it keeps listening on a Kafka topic.

What would be the proper syntax, to change / add in this method, so it could be called as a package / library, and a message handling method would be passed to it by the calling app:

```
...

import kafkaReceiver;

messageHandler(String message){
......
}

kafkaReceiver.receiveMessage(messageHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Java. There is no such a concept `method to method`. There are objects, typically called `services`. So, you can extract your `@KafkaListener` service and inject into it an appropriate service implementation:

```
public class MyKafkaListener {

    private final MyService myService;

    public MyKafkaListener(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }


    @KafkaListener
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
            this.myService.handleMessage(message);
    }

}

...

@Bean
public MyKafkaListener myKafkaListener() {
   return new MyKafkaListener(myServiceImpl());
}
```

Comment: hello this maybe outdated thread, but can this be done otherwise?
so i tried to creating @Component to my KafkaListener class. Inside this class there are listeners that store the incoming records to a List<String>.. and from other class(in this case, Test Class), i Autowired the KafkaListener class and try to get the List of message, but somehow i always got empty list.. but if i check in the listener, there are records consumed by the listener
here's for full question and code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72927003/java-spring-test-class-cant-access-variable-from-autowired-component/