# Java Spring Test Class Can't access variable from @Autowired component

Tags: java, spring, junit, integration-testing, spring-kafka

so, i have this `@Component` class for listening topic from kafka

```
@Component
@Data
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConsumer {
    public List<String> saveReserveStock = new ArrayList<>();

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic")
    public void listenReserveStock(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) {
        System.out.println("==================================================================");
        System.out.println("consuming records at: " + DateTime.now().toLocalDateTime());
        System.out.println("consuming topic: " + consumerRecord.topic());
        saveReserveStock.add(consumerRecord.value().toString());
        saveReserveStock.add("dummy data");
        saveReserveStock.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("consumed at: " + DateTime.now().toLocalDateTime());
        System.out.println("==================================================================");
        System.out.println("end at: " + DateTime.now().toLocalDateTime());
    }

    public void emptyConsumer(){
        saveReserveStock = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

and this is embedded kafka configuration

```
@Slf4j
@EnableKafka
public abstract class EmbeddedKafkaIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    protected static EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker = new EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1, false);

    @Autowired
    protected KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer;
    @Autowired
    private ReactorKafkaProducer reactorKafkaProducer;

    protected abstract void setUp();

    private static boolean started;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createBroker(){
        log.info("start test class");
        Map<String, String> propertiesMap = new HashMap<>();
        propertiesMap.put("listeners", "PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092");
        embeddedKafkaBroker.brokerProperties(propertiesMap);
        if (!started) {
            try {
                embeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet();
                log.info("before class - kafka connected to: "+embeddedKafkaBroker.getBrokersAsString());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Embedded broker failed to start", e);
            }
            started = true;
        }
    }
    @Before
    public void doSetUp() {
        log.info("before - kafka connected to: "+embeddedKafkaBroker.getBrokersAsString());
        kafkaConsumer.emptyConsumer();
        this.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        kafkaConsumer.emptyConsumer();
        embeddedKafkaBroker.getZookeeper().getLogDir().deleteOnExit();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void destroy(){
        log.info("end test class");
    }

}
```

then in my test class, using `@Autowired` for that `KafkaConsumer` class

and in the test class i have this to get message from the listener that already consumend

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ImsStockApplication.class},
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Slf4j
public class IntegrationTest extends EmbeddedKafkaIntegrationTest {
    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;
    @Autowired
    private KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer;
    @Autowired
    private ReactorKafkaProducer reactorKafkaProducer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        RestAssured.port = port;
    }

    @Test
    public void success_SubDetail() {
        reactorKafkaProducer.send("topic", event).block();

        Awaitility.await().atMost(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> {
            log.info("AWAITILITY AT: " + DateTime.now().toLocalDateTime());
            Assert.assertTrue(kafkaConsumer.getFailDecreaseGoodsReceipt().size() > 0);
            Assert.assertTrue(kafkaConsumer.getSaveReserveStock().size() > 0);
            Assert.assertTrue(kafkaConsumer.getSaveBindStock().size() > 0);
        });
    }
}
```

but the result sometimes got failure (list empty)...
it's like the list variable is empty, while it should be not empty

below is the log where the listener receive the message and store it to the list

```
==================================================================
consuming records at: 2022-07-10T14:16:46.748
consuming topic: topic
{"id":9721,"eventId":"eventId","organizationCode":"ORG","createdDate":1657437282742,"lastModifiedDate":1657437282742,"routingId":"routingId"}
dummy data
consumed at: 2022-07-10T14:16:46.748
==================================================================
end at: 2022-07-10T14:16:46.748
```

and in my test class when i tried to access the variable, it got empty. it keep waiting for the list to be filled

```
AWAITILITY AT: 2022-07-10T14:16:46.829
AWAITILITY AT: 2022-07-10T14:16:46.945
AWAITILITY AT: 2022-07-10T14:16:47.056
AWAITILITY AT: 2022-07-10T14:16:47.164
AWAITILITY AT: 2022-07-10T14:16:47.273
AWAITILITY AT: 2022-07-10T14:16:47.384
AWAITILITY AT: 2022-07-10T14:16:47.490
AWAITILITY AT: 2022-07-10T14:16:47.598
```

if we looked at the timestamp, the list shouldn't be empty right? but why my test got failed?
Where did i go wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the question lacks information... So providing not a real answer but rather a series of possible answers that can help to find the solution.

There are many possible reasons for the test to fail and its not necessarily because of your test code.

One possible reason is that when you connect to kafka you start to listen to the "latest" messages (offset = latest) In this case you won't be able to consume the messages that are already in the topic.
While this can be the answer to the question really, but Maybe you can post the code that actually sends the message to the topic. And this is the real question here.

Another possible reason is the number of partitions. If the listener is configured to use the same consumer group as other listeners that might exist in the running application - maybe it doesn't get the partition that eventually receives the message

Its also possible that the reason is in the code itself, but again you don't show all the configuration at least the configuration of the test here.

An example of such a possible issue is that the `@KafkaListener` is not handled properly, so spring makes a spring bean from the component (after all it can be autowired from within the test) but doesn't plug in the whole kafka infrastructure under the hood.

Comment: i updated the question.. is that enough? or is there anything else i need to inform?